# Save all $_GET values except one to the next page

Tags: php, pagination, get

I have a table which is filled with some rows and it is showed based on a pagination script I have. In this table there are two GET forms which handle the sorting and the rows per page. When the forms are sent the URL becomes for example: `?page=2&order=desc&view=10`.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass those `order` and `view` values when i click on a different page. This is the link to the previous (or next) page on my script:

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">Prev</a></li>";
```

`$prev` is `$page - 1` where `$page` is `$_GET['page']`. When I am on page 2 and I need to get to page 1, i just click the above link and I need to take with me `order` and `view` on the URL.

I tried with

```
$build_query = http_build_query($_GET);
```

editing the above line with this:

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev{$build_query}\">Prev</a></li>";
```

But of course as soon as i click the link it gives me

`?page=1page=2&order=desc&view=10`

So page is repeated. I also tried to `unset($_GET['page']);` but I don't know how to pass the previous page value to set then `$_GET['page']` correctly.

**EDIT 1**:

The entire pagination code is written inside a function so $_GET values to pass is different between pages.

Comment: Might need more info on your procedure.

Comment: @Jonast92 I edited with some more info on how I used `http_build_query($_GET)`. Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: did you check the spelling on `page` ? array key can never be duplicated..weird...

Comment: @Andrew It gets duplicated because i write `page=$prev` just before `{$build_query}`, but I don't know how to get rid of `page=$prev` and just pass the $prev value to the `$_GET['page']` when I click on the link. I might try saving $prev to a variable and then use `unset($_GET['page'])` and `$_GET['page'] = $variable`. Let me see.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$prev` is just `$page - 1` where `$page` is `$_GET['page']`. It is quite simple. If i am on page 2, `$prev` is 1. Also `$targetpage` is `index.php`.

Comment: @reyy I have never heard of duplicated array key nor it possible I think....else how would you tell the difference or call that value....

Comment: @Andrew I'm really sorry, it was my fault. Check now, I fixed. It gives me ``?page=(previouspage)page=2&order=desc&view=10``

Comment: @reyy ohh, in that case your url will not be parsed correctly, because there is a missing `&` between `page`, once you have a `&`, it will only come down to a single `page` variable and whatever is the latter one will be displayed

Comment: I get kinda fed up trying to answer **incomplete** questions.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're right, sorry for that I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build you own query string function:

```
function generate_query_string($page_num)
{
    $query = '?';
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'page') {
            $query.=$key.$page_num;
        } else {
            $query.=$key.'='.$value.'&';
        }
    }
    // remove trailing '&'
    return substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 1);
}
```

You can pass the desired page number in as an argument when you call the function.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and it was giving me `?page=1?order=asc&view=30` but I just edited `$query = '?'` to `$query = '&'` and It works like a charm.

Comment: Oh yea, I'll make that change. Actually, I will update it so that you can generate the whole thing in just this function. Doesn't make sense to set the string two different places